# Stock recovery for HTC M8 (KTU84P)

Tags: recovery-mode, htc-one-m8

I've been trying to unroot my HTC One M8 (India) for a long time and get it to 100% stock so that I can receive OTAs. It took me some time to get it all together but I still have the wrong stock recovery.img.

So when I download the OTA and the phone goes into recovery to install it, the error message says:

> Package expects build fingerprint of htc/htc_asia_india/htc_m8:4.4.4/KTU84P/405596.1:user/release-keys or htc/htc_asia_india/htc_m8:5.0.1/LRX22C/454154.8:user/release-keys. This device has htc/htc_asia_india/htc_m8:4.4.2/KOT49H/330216.6:user/release-keys.

Where can I find the correct recovery (KTU84P)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's why it is recommended to  always make a backup of your stock recovery, HTC does not officially provide them! 
I found [this collection](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=60211779&postcount=4), may be you'll find one made for your phone.